# Using VBA to insert a formula using existing cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Okay, I have a basic understanding of how to record macros in VBA.

I have a bunch of cells, each referencing cells on other sheets. (Ex: =R!$A$1).  These cells don't match the destination cells (for example, D3 on the primary sheet contains =R!$A$1, and the next entry is F3 referencing =R!$A$4).

Using VBA, I tried replacing the first instance with =IF(R!$A$1="", "TBA", R!$A$1).  This recorded and worked for the cell in question, but when I moved to F3 and ran the macro, it replaced the cell with the exact same formula.  How do I get VBA to take the existing text in the cell as replacement text, instead of blindly copying the first example?

My first thought was `ActiveCell.R1C1 = "=IF( ActiveCell.R1C1 = "", "TBA", ActiveCell.R1C1)` but that failed to compile.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `R1C1` (should that be `FormulaR1C1`?) but your formulas seem to be in A1 format?  It's not very clear exactly what you want to do though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (if I understand what it is you're trying to do...)

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim frm As String
    If ActiveCell.HasFormula Then      'formula in cell?
        frm = ActiveCell.Formula       'read the existing formula
        frm = Right(frm, Len(frm) - 1) 'remove the `=`
        ActiveCell.Formula = _
             "=IF(" & frm & "="""",""TBA""," & frm & ")" 'set new formula
    End If
End Sub
```